# scp error when copying files

Tags: scp

I am trying to use the `scp` command but I'm getting the following error:

```
permission denied  
lost connection
```

I get this when I use `scp` to copy a file from a master node to a slave node.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think error in giving permission to folder which has the authorized_keys file

use chmod and set the permissions

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more like your error, ya?

```
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

The simplest problem is that you don't have permissions to access the directories specified on at least one end of the copy operation, or you may just have a bad login.

1. You could try using `sudo chown -R
   *username*` to make sure you have rights to the target directories on
   both ends.
2. Check your directory specifications, make sure that you are using ~/Documents for instance instead of /Documents. Very different locations.

If you've got a bad login, I can't help you there, sorry. Try just ssh-ing into the target(s) make sure you can.

You could check out [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)  for more help

Comment: Thank you arrdem for the precision, i.e. "permissions to access the directories specified on at least one end of the copy operation".